# Determining the relationship between plate separation distance and capacitance experimentally

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

On a lab I recently did, I measured the capacitance between aluminium foils over a range of distances. One of the subsequent questions was to determine the function that best describes the relationship between separation distance and capacitance, which I’m having trouble with.

First, I’ve considered using a linear regression to model the relationship - but this equation doesn’t correspond to the form of C ∝ 1/d.

Then I attempted using a power series, and while this resulted in an inverse relationship between the two variables, the power of d isn’t 1 and thus the equation also doesn’t correspond to C ∝ 1/d.

How should I manipulate my experimental values to arrive at an equation of the form I require?

Comment: Do you think this formula is valid without limitations?

Answer (score 1):

The power series fit $d^p$ should have $p$ close to -1 if your experiements were done correctly. Can't force experimental data to be correct! An easier way to fit power laws is to make a linear fit to the log-log representation of the data, i.e., take $\log C$ and $\log d$ and plot these. This should give a straight line with slope approx -1.